# Не получается записать InputField(Multi Line) в List<string>

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу записать значение каждой строки `InputField` в `List<string>`.

Пробовал

1. `List = (InputField.text).ToList`
2. `List = InputField.text`

Так как `InputField.text` это тип `string` , я не могу преобразовать его в `List<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
string text = InputField.text;
string[] lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
```

Или, если C# так не поддерживает в Unity этот вариант, то тогда так:

```
string[] lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Чтобы получить список из массива

```
List<string> list = lines.ToList();
```

Но если нет необходимости список модифицировать, я бы советовал оставить массив.